# Tracking external ad links with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I  am using `_trackPageview()` to track external links for my ads. But where in my Google Analytics dashboard can I find the tracking information? I checked the Google Doc information, but it doesn't say.

Comment: And where is the save button for the Google Goals?! http://i.imgur.com/E2rpS.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them under "**Top Content Report**". Here's what Google says about this:

> To verify that _trackPageview is being called correctly, you can check your Top Content report 24 to 48 hours after the updated tracking code has been executed. You should be able to see the assigned page name in your report.

See http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55529 and http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55527